# Cloning and running Azure VM with the same Internal IP address without impacting the existing Production VM?

Tags: azure, azure-networking

I need to know what's the steps that I need to follow successfully to clone the Azure VM into separate Subscription with the same IP address (Private IP only)

From:

```
 Subscription: CORP-PROD-AZ-CC
 Resource Group: CORP-PROD-ERP-RG
 VM Name: PROD-ERP01-VM
 IP:10.17.1.10
```

Into:

```
 Subscription: CORP-TEST-AZ-CC
 Resource Group: CORP-TEST-ERP-RG
 VM Name: TEST-ERP01-VM
 IP:10.17.1.10
```

As you can see the above, the VM is using VNet with the Internal IP assigned 10.17.1.10
How to clone it successfully to different Subscription, and then retain the same IP address, and start it up without impacting the Production VM?

I assume the VM in different Subscription and Resource group, can have the same IP internal address and can be tested with the Network disconnected to avoid IP address conflict?

The server PROD-ERP01-VM [10.17.1.10] is currently accessed by multiple OnPremise servers via Express Route.

Do I need to disconnect the vNIC on the cloned VM to avoid production IP conflict?

Or this is not a problem since the different VNET can be created with the same subnet range in another RG and Subscription, under the same tenant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The IP address is a function of the network interface azure object, not the VM. You need to create the NIC and assign it a static IP for the value you require.

Comment: in this case, can I assign the same IP address for two different VMs, on a separate RG, and separate Subscription?

Comment: So long as the two vNets are separate, not peered or connected in any way, yes you can assign the same IP.

Comment: how do you create VNET that is not peered? Is that even possible ?

Comment: You just create a vNet, peering is something you have to consciously apply